# How to make an appropriate 2D collider for a character in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, platform, collider

I have a simple 2D character, which is a cat, to which I want to assign an appropriate collider. My game is consisting of this cat jumping from platform to platform, but when it lands it kinda bounces a little off the platform, which is not good.

I have assigned a Polygon Collider 2D, which obviously does not work properly. 
I have a 2D Material attached to the platform with 0 bounciness, and -50 friction.

I am making my cat jump by adding force to its rigidbody.

I want my cat to remain stuck on the platform when it lands.

Can anyone help me how to solve this problem? 
Thanks.

If I have to provide any code tell me.

Comment: Is your movement code in `Update` or `FixedUpdate`?

Comment: @CNuts I have FixedUpdate in two of my scripts, while in the others I have Update... :)

Comment: So the code for the cat jumping is in which?

Comment: @Cnuts It's in Update :)

Comment: Could you try changing it for `FixedUpdate`? :)

Comment: @CNuts Same result... I can also notice the delay in rendering the animations

Comment: Hmm weird. Try putting Rigidbody2d > Collision detection to Continuous instead of Discrete. I think its not supported for polygon, you could try it with a boxcollider.

Comment: Make sure both the cat's collider and whatever it's colliding with have a `PhysicsMaterial2D` with `Bounciness` set to 0.

Comment: Already tried changing "Discrete" to "Continuous", same result. Both objects (cat and platform) have bounciness set to 0.